# Insert value in cassandra columnfamily in c#.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cassandra

I face problem for inserting value in Cassandra database.
Please suggest me some code for inserting value in database

```
var empRecord = new EmployeeEntity()
           {
               employeeid=2,
               age=23,
              employeename=txtName.Text,
              salary=5001


           };
  var employeeRecord = new CassandraEntity<List<Column>>().SetColumnFamily(columnFamily).SetKey(empRecord.employeeid).SetData(empRecord);
                   ctx.ColumnList.InsertOnSubmit(employeeRecord);
                   ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

i getting error for inserting value in Cassandra database

Error like -> Not enough bytes to read value of component 0

How to solve it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which driver you are trying to use, but this works with the DataStax C# CQL3 driver.

First, connect to Cassandra and get your session:

```
cluster = Cluster.Builder().WithCredentials(_user, _password).AddContactPoint(_node).Build();
Session session = cluster.Connect();
```

Then, insert data using the following:

```
String strCQL1 = "UPDATE yourKeyspaceName.employee SET age=?, "
  + "employeename=?, Salary=? "
  + "WHERE employeeid=?";
PreparedStatement statement = session.Prepare(strCQL1);
BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);
boundStatement.Bind(age, txtName.Text, salary, empRecord.employeeid);
session.Execute(boundStatement);
```

In this case, Cassandra will perform an "UPSERT," inserting the data if it does not exist and updating if it does.  Just make sure that your primary key(s) are in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try This solution ,

```
string query = " insert into employee (employeeid,age,employeename,salary) values (" + txtId.Text + ",31,'" + strNameHex.Trim() + "'," + myHexNumber + ")";
                  txtQuery.Text = query;
                  context.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
                  context.SaveChanges();
```

It's help you